# System UI Crash on Boot

Tags: crashes

I was playing with the developer options on my Droid Turbo, and I think I accidentally hit Force RTL Layout, which crashed System UI. I tried rebooting and now it also says "Unfortunately, System UI has stopped". I cannot access any apps or settings, even in safe mode. Is there any way I can turn this setting off or reset the developer options, maybe through a computer? I would like to not have to do a factory reset. I am running Android 5.1

Comment: Is the USB debugging enabled or custom Recovery installed?

Comment: USB debugging might be enabled, not sure about either.

Comment: If the USB debugging is enabled, then you can clear Settings data using ADB followed by a Reboot. Things should become normal then. But for that, you need to confirm whether it is enabled or not?

Comment: I cannot confirm whether or not USB debugging is on since I cannot access settings, but I can say Windows doesn't do anything with it plugged into my computer. I have Linux with the ADB installed on my laptop if you could tell me the steps required to reset the settings.

Comment: Run your Linux with root account if possible or open a Terminal and gain root privileges in it. After that, connect your device into Laptop using USB, type `adb devices` in terminal; and tell the output here.

Comment: `sudo adb devices` returns "List of devices attached" with nothing listed, so I would assume this means USB debugging is off?

Comment: There are two possible things here: either the Linux is not detecting the device for some other reason even when root privileges are given (can happen, but might be unlikely here), or as you thought, the USB debugging is off, in which case I would rather ask again whether Custom Recovery is installed or not (is the device rooted, or have you ever taken a Nandroid backup or flashed a ROM)? // Otherwise, factory reset seems to be the only option here, but may be other users can help.

Comment: Linux does make a noise when I boot the phone, so it is detecting it. I don't exactly know what custom recovery is so I would assume that is not installed, and this is a Verizon device, so no custom ROMs, and no backups.

Comment: In that case, all hands up here besides factory reset. But may be other users can help you out in this case. So good luck!

Comment: Should I have to do a factory reset, is there any way I could get files from the device before I reset it?

Comment: @Alex ADB or Recovery should work for retrieving files.

Comment: @MatthewRead USB debugging is off (or at least not detected even in `sudo adb devices`) so no ADB at least when Android is running. But yeah, stock Recovery can be given a try.